# Get 32-bit zip files using 64-bit Java

Tags: java, zip, 64-bit

When I zip files using 64 bit Java, the zip file show up as empty on Windows 7. Is there a way to force 32 bit version of zip using 64 bit Java?

EDIT:
I'm able to open/unzip it using third party tools like BeyondCompare. When I browse that file through Windows 7, the content is empty. Unzipping it using Win 7 gives me 'Invalid zip file' error.

```
public static void zipFiles(Collection<String> fileLocations, String targetZipFile){
    if( fileLocations == null || fileLocations.size() <= 0 ){
        return;
    }
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    try{
        ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(targetZipFile));

        FileInputStream in = null;
        String fileName = null;
        for( String fileLoc : fileLocations ){

            fileName = fileLoc.substring(fileLoc.lastIndexOf(File.separator));
            // Add ZIP entry to output stream.
            out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileName));

            in = new FileInputStream(fileLoc);

            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }

            // Complete the entry
            out.closeEntry();
            in.close();
        }

        // Complete the ZIP file
        out.close();

    }catch(IOException ioe){
        LOGGER.error(ioe.getMessage(),ioe);
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't think 64 bit is a problem, since you write data to hard drive. Maybe you use some weird encoding?

Comment: or you do not flush / close your streams?

Comment: There is no such thing as a 32bit/64bit zip file... You probably have problems writing the zip file in the first place. Code?

Comment: @fge I added the code, but I'm able to open up that zip file using other tools like BeyondCompare. However, Windows 7 doesn't show any content, and I get 'Invalid zip file' when I try to extract it. Again, it works fine using other tools.

Comment: Uuh... Do you happen to have non ASCII filenames in this zip file?

Comment: @fge There's only one file there - `customersWithActiveUsers_20140314_151559.csv`

Comment: A zip will only be 64-bit if it contains more than 65335 files, or requires integers for file sizes/crc32s that are larger than int32 max. Long story short, if you want a 64-bit zip, zip something large.